# join two dataframes with same column name consecutively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"],"B":[0,1,1,1]})


   df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Panda", "Panda", "Zootopia", "Zootopia"],"B":[0,1,1,1]})
```

Output:

```
     A          B
0   foo         0
1   foo         1
2   foo         1
3   bar         1
4   Panda       0
5   Panda       1
6   Zootopia    1
7   Zootopia    1
```

Join df and df1 like given in the expected output.

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df,df1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or `reset_index` for `concat`:

```
print(pd.concat([df,df1]).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `DataFrame.append`?

```
In [140]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"],"B":[0,1,1,1]})
     ...:
     ...:
     ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Panda", "Panda", "Zootopia", "Zootopia"],"B":[0,1,1,1]})

In [141]: df.append(df1)
Out[141]:
          A  B
0       foo  0
1       foo  1
2       foo  1
3       bar  1
0     Panda  0
1     Panda  1
2  Zootopia  1
3  Zootopia  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `ignore_index=True` for avoid duplicated index values:

```
df = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True) 
print (df)

          A  B
0       foo  0
1       foo  1
2       foo  1
3       bar  1
4     Panda  0
5     Panda  1
6  Zootopia  1
7  Zootopia  1
```